# JVMTI Agent_OnLoad handler can't create a System Property

Tags: java, jvmti

I'm using the JVM Tool Interface. I'm trying to create a SystemProperty in the Agent_OnLoad event using the SetSystemProperty() call.  If the property exists, it correctly sets a new value.  However, if the property does not exist, SetSystemProperty returns an error code saying it cannot write the property (error 98).

Is there another way to create a system property early in the JVM's life, before classes get loaded?

5/24/12 update: As an agent, I am loaded by various programs. I can't ask the programs to set this property (not practical in my use case). I'm looking for a way to do set the property from the agent code itself. After a lot of experimenting, I've come to the conclusion that it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already looked at the JVMTI docs for system properties, it would be worthwhile:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#props

It looks like there is a distinction made between VM system properties and the properties managed by `java.lang.System`. If you really want to set a property that will be available via `System.getProperty`, then you're probably stuck with doing it via JNI (per the JVMTI docs).

Comment: I missed that little distinction before.

Answer (score 0):

Add the property using `-D<property name>=<property value>` when launching from the command line.

> system properties may be set before they have been used in the
>   start-up of the VM

taken from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#starting

Comment: Well, this would work, but doesn't help me. I'll update the question to be more clear - my code is the agent, and the agent needs to do the update.